Title: Error "pageData.map is not a function" when rendering table in React
I'm encountering an issue when trying to render a table in a React application. I'm receiving the following error: "pageData.map is not a function". It seems like the problem is occurring in the part where I'm trying to map the data received from the context to render the table rows.
Here's the snippet of the Table component code:
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { MdEdit } from 'react-icons/md';
import { IoMdTrash } from 'react-icons/io';
import './Table.css';
import { DataContext } from '../../context/DataContext';

const Table: React.FC = () => {
  const { pageData } = useContext(DataContext);

  return (
    <div className="TableContainer">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="Name">Nome</th>
            <th className="Date">Data</th>
            <th className="Lab">Laboratório</th>
            <th className="Principle">Princípio Ativo</th>
            <th className="Actions">Ações</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Array.isArray(pageData) && pageData.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.published_at}</td>
              <td>{item.company}</td>
              <td>
                {item.active_principles.map((principle) => (
                  <span key={principle.id}>{principle.name}<br /></span>
                ))}
              </td>
              <td>
                <ActionIcons />
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

A snippet of Context API code:
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { api } from '../lib/axios';

interface Data {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  published_at: string;
  company: string;
  documents: Document[];
  active_principles: ActivePrinciple[];
}

interface Document {
  id: string;
  expedient: string;
  type: string;
  url: string;
}

interface ActivePrinciple {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface DataContextType {
  pageData: Data[];
  fetchData: () => Promise<void>;
  fetchPageData: (pageNumber: number) => Promise<void>;
}

export const DataContext = createContext<DataContextType>({
  pageData: [],
  fetchData: async () => {},
  fetchPageData: async () => {},
});

export const DataProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState<Data[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); 
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get<Data[]>('data');
      setPageData(response.data); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  const fetchPageData = async (pageNumber: number) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get<Data[]>(`data?_page=${pageNumber}`);
      setPageData(prevData => {
        return JSON.stringify(prevData) === JSON.stringify(response.data) ? prevData : response.data;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching page data:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{ pageData, fetchData, fetchPageData }}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

I've checked and I'm sure that pageData is defined and contains the necessary data. However, it seems like the issue occurs when I try to call map on pageData.
To provide some context, I'm using JSON Server to simulate a REST API and provide data for my React application. The component structure involved in this issue includes ComponentWrapper, Table, and DataContext.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can resolve this error?
